# Stability of isomers of N4O

Tags: stability, molecular-structure, isomers

I have googled and found that the structure of $\ce{N4O}$ is linear with a positive and negative charge on 2 nitrogen atoms. But, the following structure seems more stable because it fulfils octet for all elements, the structure has no charge and it is resonance stabilised:
[image]

Why is this not the actual structure of $\ce{N4O}$? Are there any destabilizing effects that outweigh the stabilizing effects in this structure? The structure doesn't seem to have much angle strain. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The real structure, too, has a complete octet for all atoms and is resonance stabilized. As for having charge, that's not a big deal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrosylazide, looks sth good about oxatetrazene is harder to find, but they both decompose easily.

Comment: This is the kind of molecule you’ve drawn, where I’m scared to touch the monitor because it might explode …

Comment: @Jan, could you please explain why it is so unstable?

Comment: I consider every molecule that has more nitrogen atoms than *insert-other-atom-type-here* to be prone to explode, that’s why ;)

Comment: But isn't this structure more stable than the linear structure?

Comment: You're wrong in thinking that everything can be explained using few rules of thumb.

Comment: @Mithoron I am not an expert in inorganic chemistry. I only know the basics of inorganic chemistry taught at my school. My teacher was unable to explain as to why this structure was unstable because I followed the basic rules to draw the lewis dot structure. That is why I approached you guys. Many of you have great knowledge in chemistry and I am hoping I can get a clear answer. SE has never let me down.

Comment: Cyclic is not inherently more stable than linear.

Comment: @Jan no it is not. My question was whether this particular molecule is more stable in the cyclic form than in the linear form.

Comment: @ShankRam Ah, if *that* is your question then the answer is ‘we cannot say *a priori*’.

Comment: @Jan with the help of various stabilizing and destabilizing effects we have in our hands, is it possible to tell which one is expected to be more stable?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33428/discussion-between-shankram-and-jan).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [The Nitrosyl Azide Potential Energy Hypersurface: A
High-Energy-Density Boom or Bust?](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja9534157) J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1996, 118, 4860-4870 :

> [Abstract] ...While the ring isomer is predicted to be the most stable structure on the
>   hypersurface, the barrier to dissociation is most likely between 1 and 2 kcal mol-1 (including zero-point vibrational
>   energy [ZPVE], the existence of any barrier becomes questionable) making isolation theoretically possible but
>   experimentally difficult. This small barrier also detracts from the attractiveness of the N4O ring structure as a high energy-density material. The trans-chain isomer, however, lies in an energy valley with higher sides, consistent
>   with its previous experimental observation.
>
> [full text]...In an ideal five-membered ring
>   with 6 $\pi$ electrons, the $\pi$ electrons would be distributed evenly
>   among all the bonds. In the present case, the highly electronegative
>   O atom prefers to keep electrons around itself, leading
>   to a partial negative charge on the oxygen. Energetically, there
>   is a certain degree of stability associated with the ring isomer,
>   although not on the order of common aromatic systems. The
>   ring isomer is predicted to be at most (DZP CISD) 20.9 kcal
>   mol-1 more stable than the trans-chain isomer; however, this
>   value decreases to 13.2 kcal mol-1 with TZ2P CCSD.
>   The ring isomer TS to dissociation into N2 and N2O is shown
>   in Figure 5. ... Energetically, the barrier to dissociation
>   is at most 15.3 kcal mol-1 (DZP CISD) and drops lower
>   with improvements in both basis set and correlation scheme.
>   In going from a DZP to a TZ2P basis set, for example, this
>   barrier drops by 5.2 kcal mol-1 for CISD and 4.3 kcal mol-1
>   for CCSD. Assuming a similar trend in moving from DZP
>   CCSD(T) to TZ2P CCSD(T), the ring dissociation barrier is
>   expected to drop to 1-2 kcal mol-1 with the addition of f-type
>   functions possibly making it even lower. A barrier of this size
>   lies below the ZPVE, throwing doubt on the existence of the
>   N4O ring isomer.

So thermodynamically, yes, the ring form is the lowest energy isomer.  However, all the isomers are unstable to decomposition and the linear isomer is in a deeper potential energy well than the ring isomer. Therefore, the linear isomer is easier to observe experimentally for kinetic reasons.

There may be additional information in [Theoretical study on structures and stabilities of N4X (X = O, S, Se, Te) series](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qua.21796/abstract) International Journal of Quantum Chemistry Volume 109, pages 226–235.